# display a specific row at the end in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

I have a table that name is "ProductName" has several categories such as "Men", "Women", "Other" and each of the categories have sub-categories.

**Table Screenshot**
[image]

And the code behind is going to show all the categories If `ParentId` is Null and show all sub-categories based on each category `parentId` relegated to categories.
I have added a new category **"Kids"** but I want to show **"Other"** at the end of the query, Now Kids would display as the last one.
I would be appreciated it If anyone could help me.Thanks

**Query:**

```
select
    bn.[ProductId],
    bn.[Name],
    bn.[Store],
    bn.[City],
    bn.[ZipCode],
    bn.[ParentId]
from
    [dbo].[ProductName] bn
order by
        case 
        when bn.ParentID is null
        then bn.ProductId 
        else    (
                select  ProductId 
                from    ProductName parent 
                where   parent.ProductId = bn.ParentID
                ) 
        end,
        case when bn.ParentID is null then 1 end desc,
        bn.ParentID
```

Comment: Not an answer sorry. Honestly this is plain and simply screaming bad DB design.  Setting up your categories and sub categories as proper related entities makes this infinitely easier.   In your Categories entities you could even have a priority attribute specifically for ordering query results

Comment: This cannot be both MySql and Sql Server. What database is it?

Answer (score 0):

Setting database design aside, I would suggest two changes to the query.

First join to the parent (which may be self):

```
join dbo.ProductName parent on parent.ProductId = COALESCE(bn.parentId, bn.ProductID)
```

and then adjust the order by to include a special case for "Other":

```
order by
    case when parent.name = 'Other' then 1 else 0 end,
    ...
```

Comment: I don't agree with setting aside the database design. Put it in the bit bucket where it belongs and start again. This table is going to be nothing but trouble.

Comment: @Mary - I get you point. Properly designing a recursive hierarchical structure in a relational database and maintaining a properly normalized form is not trivial. The OP would do well to search for and study articles on database design and normalization.

My intent was not to dismiss the design shortcomings, but to answer the specific how-to question within the limits of the current design.